# How resolve a 403 Forbidden message Mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, http-status-code-403

> 403 => Net::HTTPForbidden for https://www.state.gov/countries-areas-archive/tunisia/page/2/ -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)

This is what i read in console , i look to scrape  a 9-pages US state Department statements about Tunisia. what is wrong?
The code seems correct Ruby Mechanize :

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
9.times do |i|

page = agent.get("https://www.state.gov/countries-areas-archive/tunisia/page/#{i+1}/")
page.search('a.collection-result_link').each do |link|
    agent.click(link)
url = agent.page.search('link[rel = "canonical"]').attr('href').text
wrapped_url = url.gsub(url, "<a href='#{url}'>الرابط</a>")  
title = agent.page.search('h1.featured-content__headline report-header__headline stars-above').text
statements = [wrapped_url, title]
puts statements
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the [logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class and set the `user_agent_alias`. This is demonstrated in the [Mechanize rubydoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize) as follows:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = Logger.new "mech.log"
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
```